# Kotlin Arrow - 'option' is deprecated. Deprecated in favor of the Effect or EagerEffect Runtime

Tags: kotlin, arrow-kt

I'm getting below depreciation warning in arrow 1.1.2, could anyone please tell me what's the correct replacement for this?

> [DEPRECATION] 'invoke(crossinline suspend OptionEffect<*>.() -> A?):
> Option' is deprecated. Deprecated in favor of the Effect Runtime

```
import arrow.core.computations.option
import arrow.core.Some
import arrow.core.none
import arrow.core.Option

suspend fun value(): Option<Int> =
//sampleStart
    option {
        val x = none<Int>().bind()
        val y = Some(1 + x).bind()
        val z = Some(1 + y).bind()
        x + y + z
    }

//sampleEnd
suspend fun main() {
    println(value())
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace this import `import arrow.core.computations.option` for `import arrow.core.continuations.option` and it should fix your deprecation.

It changes the runtime with a package change, there is no breaking change in the Kotlin API.

Comment: I struggled very much to figure out this simple solution. I wish the Deprecated tag in the arrow lib explained this so clearly

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @SomaiahKumbera, I thought this was also explicitly stated in the deprecation message. Seems not :( A contribution or issue on GitHub to improve this would be very welcome, otherwise I will try to improve this before it’ll get hard removed in 2.x.x